# Chaining multiple filters() in Django having different lists

Tags: django, django-views, django-filter, django-listview

I've been trying to use two different filter conditions having 2 different set of lists. Here, `filter(condt.1)` is working and `filter(condt.2)` is working; but when I use `filter(condt.1).filter(condt.2)` it's working differently i.e. not working in the way I had assumed.
Here is my situation:

1. This one is working properly: `posts = Post.objects.filter(author__profile__in=[logged_in_user.id])`
2. This one is also working properly: `posts = Post.objects.filter(author__profile__followers__in=[logged_in_user.id])`

But I am not getting the way to combine these two filters in one. Here is what I've tried:

```
logged_in_user = request.user
posts = Post.objects.filter(author__profile__in=[logged_in_user.id]).filter(author__profile__followers__in=[logged_in_user.id])
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need this filters working like `filter1 OR filter2`, you can use [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q) with `|` operator

```
from django.db.models import Q

logged_in_user = request.user
posts = Post.objects.filter(
    Q(author__profile__in=[logged_in_user.id]) | 
    Q(author__profile__followers__in=[logged_in_user.id])
)
```

In your example django gives you result matching both filters at the same time.

Comment: There is any reason to use `followers_in`? I think is ok to use `followers=request.user`.

Comment: What if I need the filters working like `filter1 AND filter2` ?

Comment: Just list filter conditions separated by commas `Post.objects.filter(author__profile__in=[logged_in_user.id], author__profile__followers__in=[logged_in_user.id])` @Arya Shesham

Comment: I've tried `Post.objects.filter(author__profile__in=[logged_in_user.id], author__profile__followers__in=[logged_in_user.id])` but its not working. @weAreStarDust

Comment: You can try `&` operator instead `|` with Q objects. But my previous comment should work too.

Comment: Thank you so much! `&` and `|` operators with `Q` objects work really good. But I got the desired result when I used the OR operator i.e. `|`. And your suggestions really helped me in clearing vital conceptual errors. Thank You again!!

Comment: @allexiusw I used `followers__in` instead of `followers= request.user` because I had to fetch the "Post-Data" of the users whom user `request.user` is following.

Comment: Glad to hear, consider accepting the answer, if it was useful. @Arya Shesham

Comment: @AryaShesham I can see the requirement even though you explaned it.